# Limit results in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, outer-join

Two tables. One contains a list of projects, another contains the stages of the projects.
I need to show the most recent stage of the project.
The SQL I have at the moment is showing all of the stages and looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.proj_name,
    a.proj_phase,
    c.proj_actions_next_action,
    c.proj_actions_next_action_date
FROM
    projects a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Projects_actions c
        ON a.proj_id = c.proj_actions_projects_link
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Clients b
        ON a.proj_clientlink = b.client_id
ORDER BY b.clientname
```

The output looks something like this:

```
proj_name | proj_phase | proj_actions_next_action | proj_actions_next_action_date
Denmark   | Active     | Call X person            | 1/1/2014
Denmark   | Active     | Call Y person            | 2/1/2014
Denmark   | Active     | Do this presentation     | 3/1/2014
Denmark   | Active     | Sell this product        | 4/1/2014
UK Asset  | Active     | Call Y person            | 1/2/2014
UK Asset  | Active     | Call X person            | 1/3/2014
UK Asset  | Active     | Call Y person            | 2/4/2014
UK Asset  | Active     | Do this presentation     | 3/5/2014
UK Asset  | Active     | Sell this product        | 4/6/2014
```

I want it to look like this: (Only showing the latest proj_actions_next_action_date)

```
proj_name | proj_phase | proj_actions_next_action | proj_actions_next_action_date
Denmark   | Active     | Sell this product        | 4/1/2014
UK Asset  | Active     | Sell this product        | 4/6/2014
```

Thanks all!

Comment: just get the max (date) out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  Q.proj_name,
        Q.proj_phase,
        Q.proj_actions_next_action,
        Q.proj_actions_next_action_date
FROM (
SELECT
    a.proj_name,
    a.proj_phase,
    c.proj_actions_next_action,
    c.proj_actions_next_action_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.proj_name 
           ORDER BY c.proj_actions_next_action_date DESC) AS RN
    ,b.clientname

FROM
    projects a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Projects_actions c
        ON a.proj_id = c.proj_actions_projects_link
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Clients b
        ON a.proj_clientlink = b.client_id
    )Q
WHERE Q.RN = 1
ORDER BY Q.clientname
```

Comment: Me too! BTW, it doesn't seem to use `Clients` table.

Comment: It was using clients table to order the results per client.

Comment: Also I'm looking at these now and implementing them into my current project. I'll let you know how well I get on :)

Comment: +1 for being the only one who got the 'order by' right. Maybe you should prefix the columns in the row_number part ?

Comment: Yeah this code worked a treat. Thanks very much for all the help! Also t-clausen.dk, I have no idea what that means, I'm pretty new to SQL but it works anyways. haha Thanks guys!

Comment: @MichaelStokoe I prefixed the columnns with a. and c.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ;with cte1 as
> (
> SELECT
>     a.proj_name,
>     a.proj_phase,
>     c.proj_actions_next_action,
>     c.proj_actions_next_action_date
> FROM
>     projects a  
> LEFT OUTER JOIN
>     Projects_actions c
>         ON a.proj_id = c.proj_actions_projects_link
> LEFT OUTER JOIN
>     Clients b
>         ON a.proj_clientlink = b.client_id
> ORDER BY b.clientname
> ),
> cte2 as
>
> (
>   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY proj_name ORDER BY proj_actions_next_action_date DESC) AS Row,
>   *
>   from cte1
>
> )
>
> select * from cte2
> where Row =1
> ```